# Unable to run java applet in web browser

Tags: java, applet

I have added one class file and one zip file into html file and some html tags like bgcolor,title,center and so on my point is that the web browser runs html code only but unable to run applet without any error how can i do that very succesfully

*[Translation attempt: I have created a simple HTML page with one java applet, a zip download link and some basic HTML formatting 'bgcolor, title, center'.  My applet does not run, and no error is displayed]*

and one thing also a single event like one click button it runs but multiple events doesn't run please answer me

*[Translation attempt: Upon clicking on the applet once (?) it works as intended, however it does not run fully to completion (?)]*

i currently use Mozilla Firefox, no ad remover is installed and there is currently no error message simply a blank box with some html (code?) features that i have used in html file

================================================================================
now after enabling console and refreshing it gives window and it contain following:-\

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_22
Using JRE version 1.6.0_22-b04 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\HONEY
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
APPLET tag missing CODE parameter.**
```

Comment: _Let me consult my crystal ball here..._ Nope, I got nothing.

Comment: wow you really need some extra details.. this is a terrible question

Comment: does this `applet` work at all in any other setting? How do you know it works?  Also how about posting your HTML? Be sure to use the CODE formatting when posting it.

Comment: -1. [A simple google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+applet+example) will reveal hundreds of examples which you could copy and adapt to your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data, that you provided is insufficient, but you can get more information from Java Console, you can configure it to always show and there you will see applet's errors if any. Configure it to "Always Show"
[link text](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml)

Another points: what browser do you use? Is there any advertisement removers installed for browser (like AdBlock +)?

Comment: i currently use mozilla firebox no such advertisement remover is not installed

Comment: and thing there is no error message simply blank box with some html features that i have used in html file

Comment: Activate Java Console (use link from my answer). After that refresh your html and you should see java icon in tray, double click on it and you will see applet's output. It will give you additional info.

Comment: i have activated java console and refreshing it gives black blank output excliding applet

Comment: your error here: "APPLET tag missing CODE parameter" Did you compile applet and you write correct path in html? Please,provide html code.

Comment: it displays java console window

Comment: ya! now my html file run in web browser but not in website

Comment: yes but how to mark it and can you tell me how to incresing reputation in our website

Comment: To mark question as answered, click "tick" button on the left of the right answer (down to the vote buttons). About reputation and how to gain it, please read this document http://stackoverflow.com/faq, section "What is reputation?"

Answer (score 3):

APPLET tag missing CODE parameter.**

Is the message in the console, which suggests to me that the "APPLET tag missing CODE parameter.**".  Which is bad grammar, but means something like..

**Wrong!**

```
<applet
  width="400"
  height="300"
>
</applet>
```

**Right/Corrrect**

```
<applet
  code="my.own.MyClass"
  width="400"
  height="300"
>
</applet>
```